# $\sum{z^n\over (n!)^\alpha}$ is an entire function of order $1/\alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

The problem is from Stein Complex analysis Chapter 5 Problem 3.

> Show that $\sum {z^n\over (n!)^\alpha}$ is an entire function of order $1/\alpha$.

The problem was already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1251686/668308), but it seems the definition of growth of order is different from mine.

> Definition. Let $f$ be an entire function. If there exist a positive number $\rho$ and constants $A,B>0$ such that
> $$|f(z)|\leq Ae^{B|z|^\rho}\quad \text{for all}\ z\in\Bbb C,$$
> then we say that $f$ has an order of growth $\leq\rho$. We define the order of growth of $f$ as
> $$\rho_f = \inf\rho,$$
> where the infimum is over all $\rho>0$ such that $f$ has an order growth $\leq\rho$.

The fact that given series is entire can be shown using the ratio test. But how can I show the order of growth is $1/\alpha$? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56068/42969

Comment: there is a fundamental (and fairly easy to prove) result that the order of growth as in your defintion is equivalent to the one given by the coefficient formula in the linked answer, so I would focus on proving that which is not that hard with simple estimates involving only positive numbers, so one has no issues dealing with $z^a$ as in the answer below; actually @Martin link gives that so i would close this as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can prove these claims: (for $a>0$)

$f(z)=\sum_n z^n / (n!)^a$ has the same order as $g(z)=\sum_n z^n / n^{an}$

and $g(z^a)=\sum_n z^{an} / n^{an}$ has the same order as $\sum_n z^n / n^n$ which has the same order as $\exp(z)$.

So $g(z^a)$ has order $1$ and $g$ has order $1/a$ and the same for $f$.

Comment: One has to be a bit careful since $g(z^\alpha)$ is not an entire function for non-integral $\alpha$.